# Install Radeon RX 570 4G Card Driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card

I try to install the card drivers, however none of them seems to work. I have used the ones that come in the purchase with the CDs, and some others from the internet. Although everyone says they installed correctly when they asked to restart the computer, nothing happens. The yellow icon is still in the device manager.

I have 64-bit windows 10.

[image]

the truth is that I do not know what to do, I think it must be a special driver. This is my team:
Motherboard = P8H61-M LE.
CPU = Intel i5-2500k 3.3 Ghz
RAM = 4G DDR3 1333 Mhz.
Power Source = Cooler Master 600w certified.
Operating System = Windows 10 64Bits Home

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the drivers completely and after a reboot install them again?

Comment: I will try to see how it goes

Comment: the truth is that I do not know what to do, I think it must be a special driver. This is my team: Motherboard = P8H61-M LE. CPU: Intel i5-2500k 3.3 Ghz RAM: 4G DDR3 1333 Mhz. Power Source: Cooler Master 600w certified. Operating System: Windows 10 64Bits Home

Comment: Check that the graphics card is inserted correctly and it has power connectors fitted.

Comment: If it is, she is giving me a screen.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment completely. Did you reseat the grphicscard and power connectors? @IslamLinarez

Answer (score 0):

Try to troubleshoot the issue as below:

1. Uninstall the original graphics driver completely;
2. Restart the computer;
3. Search the registry, delete the registry key with **Radeon**;
4. Restart your computer;
5. Download the corresponding driver in the link below and reinstall the driver.

Radeon™ RX 570 Drivers & Support

https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-570

If we still have the problem, it is recommended to right click on **Radeon RX 570 Series**->Select **Properties**->**General**->If there is any error information in **Device status**, if there is some error message, we can try to resolve it according to the error message.

[image]